# What is faster way to connect to SQL database on Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I understand there are two ways for dockerized application to cennect to Cloud SQL database:

- setting db Private Ip
- attaching cloud_sql sidecar to docker

Which one is faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bit of confusion here - by `cloud_sql` sidecar, you are referring to using the [Cloud SQL proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy) in a sidecar pattern as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-kubernetes-engine#proxy).

The proxy has two different connection methods - it uses either Public IP or Private IP when connecting to your Cloud SQL instance. You can specify which you want it to use with the `--ip_address_types` flag ([example](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy#private-ip)).

When it comes to latency between Public and Private IPs, Private IP are typically faster. This is because private IPs stay local within Google's infrastructure.